# Oracle: getting an average by week for the timespan of available data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some data that shows daily logins by clients on every available date they logged in that streches back a few years.

```
     date       month    clientId   loginCount  
 ------------ --------- ---------- ------------ 
  01/01/2021   01-2021       1234          234  
  02/01/2021   01-2021       1234          978  
  01/02/2021   02-2021       6547           45  
  01/02/2021   02-2021        345           86  
....
```

For each client, I would like to generate the average number of times they login every week for however long they have corresponding date entries in the table :

```
  clientId   avgWeeklyLoginCount  
 ---------- --------------------- 
      1234                   125  
      6547                    26  
       345                    48
```

I understand `'IW'` could be used in the TO_CHAR function to do this, e.g.

```
    SELECT 
        TO_CHAR(date,'IW'),
        clientId,
        SUM(loginCount) as summedCount
    FROM 
        logins
    GROUP BY 
        TO_CHAR(date,'IW')
```

but not sure how to get an average by client id from this. any help will be appreciated!

Comment: How do you want to treat weeks with no logins?

Comment: @GordonLinoff weeks with no logins should just be ignored, i only want count weeks where there was some activity

Comment: 31/01/2020 and 01/01/2021 same week or not?

Comment: @User9123 If they fall within the same 7 day week then yes. i.e. start counting a week from the first day they login and then carry on counting from there

Answer (score 0):

You can using it as example. It can be looks like unnecessary overcomplicated:

```
ceil((in_date - trunc(to_date('06.01.0001', 'dd.MM.yyyy'), 'IW'))/7)
```

It means number of week since 1 CE. If your dates contain within single year you can use `TO_CHAR(date,'IW') or TO_CHAR(date,'WW')` instead of.

```
with logins(in_date, clientId, loginCount) as (
    select to_date('01/01/2021 01:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:MI:SS'), 1234, 234 from dual union all
    select to_date('02/01/2021 01:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:MI:SS'), 1234, 978 from dual union all
    select to_date('01/02/2021 01:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:MI:SS'), 6547,  45 from dual union all
    select to_date('01/02/2021 01:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:MI:SS'),  345,  86 from dual union all
    select to_date('31/12/2020 01:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:MI:SS'),  347,  1 from dual union all
    select to_date('01/01/2021 01:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:MI:SS'),  347,  1 from dual 
)
select
    clientId, avg(loginCount) avgLoginCountPerWeek
from (
    select
        week_number, clientId, sum(loginCount) loginCountPerWeek
    from (
        select 
            ceil((in_date - trunc(to_date('06.01.0001', 'dd.MM.yyyy'), 'IW'))/7) week_number, clientId, loginCount
        from 
            logins
    ) t
    group by 
        week_number, clientId
)  
group by
    clientId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregation query and `count(distinct)`:

```
select clientid,
       count(*) / count(distinct trunc(in_date, 'WW')) as avg_per_week
from logins
group by clientid;
```